# How to detect a network was broken down with ZeroMQ monitor mechanism?

Tags: c#, android, zeromq

---

## A. Description

*I am using ZeroMQ monitor and I find that it works when logic disconnection but does not work when network broken down (unplug my cable).*

For example:

- I launch client app on an android pad, then launch a server app on my windows laptop. They are connected through a router with cables.
- Everything will be OK with monitor if I close or open either client app or server app manually. Namely, the monitor on both sides can receive a 'Connect' or an 'Accept' and a 'Disconnect' event.
- But If I unplug cable on the server side, while the client and server are connected and running, the monitors on both sides can not detect the 'Disconnect' event.

Is the monitor designed like this?

**If so, are there any solutions to detect network broken down ( a cable unplug event ) except heartbeats?**

**If not, how to use the ZeroMQ's original monitor mechanism to solve this problem? Can a `setTCPKeepAlive()` interface be useful?**

---

## B. System environment

My scenario is as below.

### Client

OS: Android, running on a pad, IDE: Android studio 2.3, lib:jeromq-0.4.3

```
// Java Code

String monitorAddr = "inproc://client.req";
ZContext ctx = new ZContext();
ZMQ.Socket clientSocket = ctx.createSocket(ZMQ.REQ);
clientSocket.monitor(monitorAddr,ZMQ.EVENT_ALL);

// Then start a montitor thread which is implemented by my own.
```

### Server

OS: Windows 7 ( 64 bit ), running on my laptop, IDE: VS2013, lib: Clrzmq4

```
// C# Code

const string MonitorEndpoint = "inproc://server.rep";

var ctx = new ZContext();
var serverSocket = new ZSocket(ctx,ZSocketType.REP);
ZError error;

// Create serverSocket pair socket
if (!serverSocket.Monitor(MonitorEndpoint, ZMonitorEvents.AllEvents, out error))
{

    if (error == ZError.ETERM)
          return ;    // Interrupted
    throw new ZException(error);
}

// Create a monitor
ZMonitor _monitor = ZMonitor.Create(ctx, MonitorEndpoint);
_monitor.AllEvents += _monitor_AllEvents;
_monitor.Start();
```

Comment: You cannot detect "half-dead" tcp connection without actively sending\receiving data over it (like heartbeat). That's because closing tcp connection requires specific handshake, and when you just unplug your cable - this handshake does not happen and connection is technically alive.

Comment: @Evk just for a record, there are many fine-tuning attributes for the `tcp://` transport-class, that ZeroMQ exposes right due to a need to allow tweaking of the "interpretation" of the standard tcp-connection FSA-transitions from the top-level abstraction ZeroMQ generates for the smart-socket archetypes, yet still keeping all the low-level activities automated and hidden from the user-code perspective. As bazza has proposed, the user-code can create an independent control-plane for using ZeroMQ own tools to "monitor" the Loss-of-Signal / Loss-of-Connection events without twiddling a tcp-layer

Comment: @user3666197 I don't see how bazza answer is fundamentally different from my comment. He says "you have to use heartbeats" and I said the same.

Comment: @Evk Thanks for your comments. By the way, if I use heartbeats, is it necessary to use zeromq monitor?  what scenario is zeromq monitor suitable for?

Comment: @user3666197 Thanks for your comments. I use setTCPKeepAlive() setTCPKeepIdle() setTCPKeepCnt() and setTCPKeepIntvl() interfaces to  tweak standard tcp-connection. But I found there was no practical effects at all. I do not know whether the way I use the interfaces is correct or not. could you please show me how to use these interfaces and what scenario are they suitable for?

Comment: Sorry, once going into the ZeroMQ orchestration of the tcp:// transport class, rather forget any other tools ( if not mentioned explicitly to tweak them, in the ZeroMQ API documentation ) but the tools ( available via .setsockopt() method ) that the ZeroMQ Context()-instance will harness. Standard tcp-connection is not under "your" imperative control, but better gets rather fully controlled from the Context()-I/O-engine. So best tell ZeroMQ Context() the settings, and it will orchestrate the rest ( this might be the reason, that your "manual" settings got overridden from this I/O-engine :o)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no built in heartbeat within ZeroMQ. I know there was some discussion on the topic within the ZMQ community some years ago, and that discussion may still be going on.

It is comparatively simple to incorporate your own heartbeat messaging in your application's use of ZeroMQ, especially if you use something like Google Protocol Buffers to encode different message types; the heartbeat is just another message.

Doing heartbeats in your application (rather than relying on some inbuilt mechanism) is ultimately more flexible; you can choose the heartbeat rate, you can choose what to do if the heartbeat fails, you can decide when heartbeating is important and not important, etc.

Consider heartbeats within a PUB/SUB pattern; it's a bit difficult for the ZMQ authors to decide on your behalf what connection / disconnection / connection-break events matter to you. And if they do build in a mechanism, but an application developer didn't want it, then it is a waste of bandwidth.

It's far easier for the ZMQ authors to leave that kind of application architectural issue to the application author (that's you!) to deal with.

With your specific example, an unplugged network cable simply looks (so far as any software can determine) like no traffic is flowing; it's the same as the application not sending anything. ZMQ doesn't send anything if the application hasn't sent anything.

If you look at the events that the socket monitor can report on, they're all the consequence of something flowing over the network connection, or something done to the socket by the application.

Comment: Exactly, bazza -- best detect from application level, having the full controls of priorities, resources spent etc. Exactly like adding a traffic-independent, ( transport mux-ed or side-band-ed ) EOW ( "Engineering-Order-Wire" + remote-sensor/contact-relay signaling ) concept that was so successfully used for this very active-loop monitoring / detection.

Comment: @bazza Thanks for your reply.  The reason why I post this is that my scenario is safety related.Emergency measure must be taken as soon as disconnection from any side (either client or server) is detected. So I consider to use zeromq monitor mechanism to see if it is suitable for this situation. After experiment, I find that it does not work. As your comments, I have to use heartbeats. Do you think ping-pong hearts is a good way to detect both sides' offline?

Comment: @EricJia, yes, ping pong is exactly the way to have confidence at both ends that the other end is still there. The ping pong interval needs to be short enough; if you need to know within 10 seconds of a failure that a failure has happened, you need to ping / pong quicker than that. All that one end knows when it receives a ping is that the other end was alive (emphasis "was") in the recent past. That is now old information, and will be reconfirmed by reception of the next ping, during which time one supposes the other end remained alive and functioning.

Comment: if "no built in heartbeat within ZeroMQ", what are the socket member functions setHeartbeatTimeout(), setHeartbeatIvl(), setHeartbeatTtl(), setHeartbeatContext(), and their respective getters for?

Comment: @foo Because at the time I answered the question libzmq version 4.2 was comparatively new (~1 year old) and was still working its way through to projects, bindings, etc; that was the version that introduced those features. But yes, these days you'd absolutely want to take advantage of those features.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to go lower than ZMQ protocol itself and access the TCP connection that specific ZeroMQ sockets use (while others do not) doesn't sound like a good idea; it would required to break encapsulation in multiple classes.

The answer @bazza gave in 2017 was entirely correct at the time.

However, newer versions of ZMQ (specifically ZMTP) include an heartbeat functionality.

Check ZMQ documentation for

| socketOpt | Java functions | name | purpose |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_IVL | get/setHeartbeatLvl() | heartbeat interval | milliseconds between ZMPT PINGs |
| ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TIMEOUT | get/setHeartbeatTimeout() | local heartbeat timeout | how long the local socket waits between received packets until it considers the connection timed out |
| ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_TTL | get/setHeartbeatTtl() | remote heartbeat timeout | if and when remote side shall consider the connection timed out |

ZMQ_HEARTBEAT_CONTEXT is still in draft state as of 2022. It is supposed to send an byte[] context with every ping.

Now, by design of ZMQ, quoting from [chapter 2 of its documentation](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/),

> The network connection itself happens in the background, and ZeroMQ
> will automatically reconnect if the network connection is broken
> (e.g., if the peer disappears and then comes back).

Thus, answering your main question, I'd expect the monitor to give you ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECT_RETRIED / ZMQ_EVENT_CONNECTED events after the underlying connection was detected as disrupted.